# Does DocuSign Connect Log include PDF Bytes?

Tags: docusignapi

While debugging my Connect listener (REST, Java), I am trying to create a PDF document based on xml in the Connect log for Demo. (I have to emulate Docusign POST request while security issues are being resolved.)
I have DocuSign Connect Service activated with “Include Documents” and "Include Certificate of Completion" checked. 
I can see Attachment element in the log’s xml but not DocumentPDF element. When saving  content as a byte array into PDF file and then trying to open it, it cannot be opened in Acrobat.
Is Attachment element in the Connect Log supposed to be a PDF document?

Here is my code to convert  to pdf file:

```
String documentName = parseXMLDoc(xmlDoc, "DocumentStatus[1]/Name");

SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HHmmsss");
String nowTime = fmt.format(new Date());
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("c:\\temp\\"+documentName.replaceAll(".pdf","_"+nowTime+".pdf"));

BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
String encodedBytes = parseXMLDoc(xmlDoc, "Attachment/Data");
byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(encodedBytes);   
out.write(decodedBytes);
out.close();
```

where parseXMLDoc is

```
public static String parseXMLDoc(Document xmlDoc, String searchToken) {
    String xPathExpression;
    try {
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        xPathExpression = "//" + searchToken;
        return (xPath.evaluate(xPathExpression, xmlDoc));
    } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code that is doing the conversion from bytes to pdf file?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I added my code to the question; I just realized that the resulting file is not a PDF file but a normal XML for <FormData><xfdf><fields>.  So my question "Is Attachment element in the Connect Log supposed to be a PDF document?" still stands.

Comment: If your connect settings are set to Include Document, then it should return in the Documents node as bytes

Comment: My Demo Connect settings have “Include Documents” and “Include Certificate of Completion” checked but there is no Documents node in the log. There is no <DocumentPDFs> node either. Are they supposed to be present in the Connect Log (as opposed to the Connect Message which is unavailable to me right now)?

Comment: <DocumentPDFs>
    <DocumentPDF>
      <Name>documentName.pdf</Name>
      <PDFBytes>{omitted}</PDFBytes>
      <DocumentType>CONTENT</DocumentType>
    </DocumentPDF>
  </DocumentPDFs>

Is what you should be seeing

Comment: The log will not show the bytes, it's only the Listener that will receive this. (this keeps the log sizes down to a manageable size)

Comment: Thank you Andrew. You resolved my doubts; Pdf part is excluded from the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the Connect log does NOT contain the actual document bytes... the documents are only included in the actual Connect pushes to your external listener.  The log files simply contain metadata around the transaction, not the actual content.

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly get a full response from DocuSign by using https://Webhook.site where you will be given a temporary URL for listening.  Plug the temporary URL into the DocuSign Connection (create a new connection for testing), and open the XML packet from the dashboard on the webhook site dashboard when it arrives from DocuSign.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.